# How a test framework behave when we add a new test case in the middle of the existing test cases?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, testcase, test-framework

I have a questions on automation framework, Suppose i have 1000 test cases. I am adding a new test case in the middle.

e.g. I have 1000 test cases. I am adding a test case in the middle (501th). What are some of the issues i may faced in the framework?

-- I am expecting it may break the execution order if all 1000 TCs have some dependencies among themselves. Apart from this issue i am not able to figure out any other possible issues, please help me in identifying the issues that can cause problem in execution of all the TCs here.

Answer (score 1):

You should **never rely on the execution order of test cases.**

Note that JUnit does not execute the test cases in the declared order - unless you use annotation `@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)`. Neither does testNG by default. Consequently, it does not really matter at which position you add the new test case.

**Besides** the changed execution order, **you might encounter side effects** if you

- change static variables which are used by other test cases as well
- change data in the database
- create, change or delete files
- close connections which are also used by other test cases